# ¿How filter this array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter

I don't know how to filter an array of objects and get only two properties, for example:

```
let datos = [ {name: Maiki, age:30, country:USA, lastname: thomas }, 
              {name: Ana, age:28, country:BELGIUM, lastname: Poirier} ]
```

I want to get a new array and it looks like this:

```
let datos = [ {name: Maiki, lastname: thomas }, 
              {name: Ana,   lastname: Poirier} ]
```

Only filter by key name and lastname of array of objects